# how to edit summary of old commits in Github desktop

Tags: github-desktop

I want to edit summary of old commit in GitHub desktop.
There looks no option to edit. I hope there is a way with GUI.
But please let me know commands if there is no way without it.

Comment: [You do understand that by modifying the edit summary, you will be creating a new commit, which is unlikely what you actually want to do.](https://help.github.com/en/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/changing-a-commit-message).  The use of the GitHub desktop client does not change this behavior.

Comment: I didn't understand and this is the answer what I wanted. so I want to receive it on answer so I can accept this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There looks no option to edit. I hope there is a way with GUI

There isn't an option due to the fact it isn't a feature set of Git.

[Changing a commit message](https://help.github.com/en/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/changing-a-commit-message), indicates that modifying the commit summary, you are actually submitting a new commit.

> In Git, the text of the commit message is part of the commit. Changing
>   the commit message will change the commit ID--i.e., the SHA1 checksum
>   that names the commit. Effectively, you are creating a new commit that
>   replaces the old one.